# Delete Many Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Why doesn't Stack Exchange delete posts that have no comments, answers, or activity for a long period of time. The number of unanswered questions continues to grow on each community (Stack Overflow: 2,710,786) , and it seems questions that are worthwhile to answer are already answered and were within a short period of time.

I understand many questions are answered in the comment section, so it seems viable to leave unanswered questions that have comments, but there are many that have never had activity (probably because they are badly worded questions, already answered before, or too individualized such that the question would not benefit the entire community).

My old question fits under all of these and has no comments or answers. It seems like it should be deleted.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886126/c-cout-output-meshes-some-names-blank

I have some strange goal that one day all questions will have answers, and the questions with no activity stand in the way.

Comment: If nothing ever happens to a question,  its gets deleted in one year. And some people are already unhappy about that, so there's going to be some resistance to shortening the waiting period. Documentation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006